# Is it inefficient to redeclare var x = obj.prop for the sake of compactness?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering what people thought of doing something like

```
var x = obj.child.prop1;
doSomething(x);
doOtherThings(x);
```

Doesn't `var` allocate more memory, rather than create a reference? Would it be worth it to avoid redefining `x` in this case and using the longer reference instead?

Comment: Even if it does allocate a *weeee* bit more memory, if your sanity is at stake, define that `x`.

Comment: In every book I read about JavaScript and performance it was always said, if you have to access a (probably nested) property more than once, assign it to a local variable. Besides that, it could be that `obj` is not even in your scope and then it is even better to cache it to avoid lookups in the scope chain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `var` does not allocate more memory. What it does is create a reference directly to `obj.child.prop1` instead of having to go through the `child` property of `obj` and the `prop1` property of that object twice each. In any case I know of, it is marginally more efficient in terms of both code size and execution speed.

Answer (score 0):

No, the 'var' keyword does not allocate more memory (beyond that necessary for the lightweight reference). It's true that [TANSTAAFL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_ain%27t_no_such_thing_as_a_free_lunch), but on the other hand the effect is going to be very minimal.

My advice: benchmark it. Probably you will find that you can't measure the difference. And with some modern browsers, you may find that it makes things a hair slower inside heavy loops.

Comment: THe memory for the stack should be preallocated, not grabbed on demand for every local variable.

Comment: @Chuck Yes, but it has to be allocated. So it does not allocate it the moment the statement is hit, but a program with 40,000 unique variables referencing the same string will require more memory than one with only one variable.

Comment: That is true only if those variable bindings all have to exist at the same time. If you have 10,000 functions each using four references to the object (which would be 40,000 variables in the whole program), I doubt the variables will take any more memory than if you made the functions all share one variable reference.

Answer (score 0):

They are doing it for readability.

If you have a reference like obj.child.prop1.prop2.prop3 it's a good idea to store it in a variable. Readabiliti is worthier than some minor perfomance issues.